# inotify on Linux kernel 3.8 with g++

Tags: c++, linux, inotify

I am trying to use inotify to detect file system changes on an Ubuntu 12.04 OS with Linux 3.8 kernel in a C++ program.

When I compile the program with gcc, it works as expected.

But when I compile the program with g++, it shows errors like -

```
inotify_test.cpp:23:21: error: ‘inotify_init’ was not declared in this scope
inotify_test.cpp:31:61: error: ‘inotify_add_watch’ was not declared in this scope
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this is appreciated.

P.S. Some internet links indicate the use of `<sys/inotify.h>`, but I do not have that file. I only have `<linux/inotify.h>`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/inotify.h`? The path `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/`should be in your default include path list, so do try to include `<sys/inotify.h>` and see what happens.

Comment: As a rule, `gcc` chokes on even the simplest piece of C++ code...so this is a mighty strange problem...

Comment: Indeed there was an inotify.h in /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu and including that solved the issue of compilation with g++. Thanks!

Comment: About the reason why this didn't work: Unlike C, C++ does not allow you to call a function without having a function declaration. The behavior of g++ is therefore correct.

Comment: @Damon nor does modern C. The behavior of c++ is of course correct because it copied everything it could from C;